# python IBM quantum lab error with qiskit enable account

Tags: python, qiskit

I am logged in IBM Quantum lab (https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab). I tried to use Shor's alghoritm with number 21. Here is Python source code:

[image]

(It is also here: https://quantumcomputinguk.org/tutorials/shors-algorithm-with-code)

But the output is:[image]

Comment: Try again later? What does the documentation say about that error?

Comment: BMQAccountError

Comment: Hello @Klovik, I am not sure it is necessary to do this if you are on the IBM Quantum Lab, how about just a `IBMQ.load_account()` instead and then the rest of your code? Does this work? By the way, if you have more questions on quantum computing, there is a StackExchange platform for it [right here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com)